# Progress indicator resource

Tags: android

I have been searching android's resources and the web but I am unable to find the resource id for the spinning progress indicator or it's seperate components. Does this resource(s) exist in `android.R`? Where?

Comment: you did like that android:id="@+id/"

Comment: clean your project first.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[you can find it here in android platform resources style](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml)
, search for **Widget.ProgressBar**